# Nginx cannot find backend service which is running

Tags: nginx

I am setting up an nginx webserver for an application with web frontend and a flask backend, each running in a docker container. The following is my nginx configuration:

```
events{}
http{
client_max_body_size 50M;
   server {
    listen 80;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;
    }

    location / {
        root /var/www/;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
  }
}
```

I can access my front end at `localhost` fine. However, my backend is not accessible.

For example, I can access the backend directly by using the correct port: `localhost:5000/api/alive` gives me the expected response, but `localhost/api/alive` gives me

```
502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.23.4
```

And the following error

```
172.27.0.1 - - [07/Apr/2023:21:22:12 +0000] "GET /api/alive HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

2023/04/07 21:22:12 [error] 108#108: *35 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.27.0.1, server: , request: "GET /api/alive HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/alive", host: "0.0.0.0"
```

How can I get my request to be routed correctly? I am new to nginx and do not understand the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0.0.0.0` is not a valid IP address. It is a notation to bind to all addresses, which is used in configuring the service that should listen.

Change your configuration to the IP address of the loopback interface.

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
}
```

Regarging the docker containers: You can't reach a port on another container via `localhost` by default. Every container has it's own network namespace, which is separated by the hosts. To reach one container from another you have three possibilities:

- host networking
- container links (legacy, will probably removed in the future)
- custom networks

Since custom networks are the most viable option I'll focus on this.

You need to create a network and reference it when you create containers.

```bash
docker network create my-network
docker run --network my-network --name db mariadb:latest
docker run --network my-network --name app -p 80:8080 myimage
```

now you can reference the container `db` by its name from inside the `app` container. You don't need to publish the ports in the db container, since they share the same network.

with docker-compose you don't need to do anything special when all containers that are involved are defined in the same yaml file, it creates a network for the containers by default.

If you have multiple yaml files and want to share a container, for example, a single database instance, you can reference it's network as an external network in the `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: I still get similar message: 172.27.0.1 - - [08/Apr/2023:12:07:51 +0000] "GET /api/alive HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

2023/04/08 12:07:51 [error] 141#141: *69 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.27.0.1, server: , request: "GET /api/alive HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/alive", host: "localhost"

Comment: `connection refused` means nothing is listening on that port. Are VMs or container involved?

Comment: Yes, the backend (port 5000) is on a separate docker container. It is exposed, and I can access it through browser.

Comment: Then read up on docker networking. It doesn't work that way. I'll update my answer when I'm on a computer again, that's to much to write on the phone. Hint: you need to create a link to the other container.

Comment: That worked! I had to use the name I had used in the docker compose file. Lets say the service name was `mycustomapp` in my docker-compose, so had to set `proxy_pass http://mycustomapp:5000` in nginx config. Please update the answer and I'll accept it.